# What is the name of the movie where visit to father's grave brings youth

Tags: story-identification, movie

An old man, while travelling, suddenly saw the village where he had lived in childhood.
When he went to the grave of his father, he fell down and woke up with his youth restored.

Comment: Welcome to SF&F!  This is a good start to the question.  Please add more details to help us to help you.  When did you see it?  Was it a new movie then?  What language/country?  Do you remember the names of any of the characters?  Etc.  The more information you add, the more likely it is that someone will be able to identify it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by, "returning to the youth".  I am guessing that you mean that he becomes young again?  Or does he somehow go back in time and live the same life over again?  Please explain.